# Is the mail containing a URL with protocol type "notes://" a phishing?

Tags: email, security, phishing

I have got an e-mail with a link looking like this

```
Notes:///3ca313f3fb36d2d482812e7fd8321707f5d8c92a/87c0c154910a8c6cabb25d7567197027847c201a
```

Is this a phishing? What application utilizes links like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes client-side URL'S: A new way to open Notes stuff in the Notes client

For example, open a personal address book with the URL: Notes:///names.nsf

Answer (score 0):

You can find the protocol handler application in the windows registry.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/
  your-protocol-name/
    (Default)    "URL:your-protocol-name Protocol"
    URL Protocol ""
    shell/
      open/
        command/
          (Default) PathToExecutable
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. There is nothing on my PC. I wonder if anyone knows what "notes://" stands for usually?

Comment: It is a custom URI handler. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier